# Get value instead of whole query

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I want to get the value of the **Encrypted** password into a string variable. but I am getting the whole query.

Here is my code:-

```
string strpassword = "select  sys.get_enc_val ('" + txtpassword.Text + "', 'F20FA982B4C2C675')  from dual";
    Response.Write(strpassword);
```

In `strpassword`  i get the whole query.

But in `Toad` the result is as

> F52377D5FFB1A47F

how to get that in oracle?

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: @lad2025: I am aware of that, but how to get the value. any idea  ?

Comment: `strpassword` is just a string. You need to open connection to DB, execute SQL, and read returned values

Comment: when will you execute this query

Comment: @lad2025: yes it is a string, i want the `encrypted` value which the function will create

Comment: Never mind the obvious SQL injection, you can't get a query's results if you don't execute it. This code simply returns the *query text* to the user. If you really need to find how to execute queries in ASP.NET, check any ADO.NET tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
string strpassword = "select  sys.get_enc_val ('" + txtpassword.Text + "', 'F20FA982B4C2C675')  from dual";
Response.Write(strpassword);
```

Then you are simply displaying the string value as you are not executing the SQL which is present inside the string.

What you are looking for is the result of the SQL which is present inside the string. To get the result of the SQL stored inside the string you need to execute it.

You can try like this:

```
string queryString = "select  sys.get_enc_val ('" + txtpassword.Text + "', 'F20FA982B4C2C675')  from dual";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader[0]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

As commented above, your query is prone to [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). A better way is to use [paramterized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) to get rid of it. Something like

```
string sql = "select  sys.get_enc_val (@myvar) from dual";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("myvar", txtpassword.Text);
```

Comment: getting error as `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`